# memcache php caching js css and images

Tags: php, javascript, css, memcached

Was after some advice/feedback if possible.

I am working on a large project and the dev team have requested we merge all the JS/CSS and cache this with memcache as one file, to speed things up.

My concern is this is not a way I'm used to working, I only want to load JS and CSS that is needed per page, for what I think is an obvious reason.

I have also been looking at some other high traffic sites and no one else seems to be doing this.

Can anyone give me some pros and cons for this approach please?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: Maybe you wan't to make this into a real question

Comment: Seems like you have two questions here - should I use memcached to cache js/css and should I combine all my js/css into a single file.  I'd suggest you post those two questions separately as they are really unrelated.

Comment: I guess the question is what are the pros and cons against caching one huge css and js file, and serving it against actually only using whats needed per page and letting the browser cache it, and what the pros and cons are for that?

Comment: @user989952 If you merge everything into one file and let the browser cache *that*, it will speed things up *very slightly* as there will only be one `GET /whatever.css ... If-Modified-Since:` per page load, but it will be negligible in terms of practical gain, I suspect. Even then, I can't see that memcache would help much for a single static file, plus every time a new client arrives/the cached copy expires, you have to transfer the whole lot again. In general I'm on your side with this, what they are suggesting sounds like a silly idea to me.

Comment: @DaveRandom Speed _what_ up very slightly?  Server performance or page load time?  While server performance may not be dramatically improved by munging to one file (though it will help a bit), the page load time can be dramatically improved, depending on the circumstances.  Page load time is what affects the user, so it's a vital factor in ensuring a good user experience.  See my answer for a mathematical breakdown.

Comment: @BenjaminCox but because no real data is being transferred - an `If-Modified-Since:` will cause a header response only if the resource has not been updated - it will be ms of gain. Plus if you keep everything separated out, you can modify a single file without needing to transfer the whole lot again. Say I have 5 CSS files and I modify a couple of characters in one of them, I only have to update the client with that one file, whereas if everything is in one I have to send all of it again just to update a couple of characters.

Comment: @DaveRandom - It's not clear - are you speaking from experience on high-traffic public-facing websites here or from a theoretical position?  Talking about the impact of modifying a couple of characters in a css file implies the latter, since high-traffic sites tend to serve millions of people in the time it takes to make, test, approve, and deploy a change.

Comment: @DaveRandom Regarding the If-Modified headers, my experience has resulted in similar numbers to Yahoo's:  http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/01/04/performance-research-part-2/.  Specifically, between 40% and 60% of the users and about 20% of the page views on any given day show up with nothing cached.  If your user experience sucks (slow load times) often-times these people will just go away :-(

Comment: @BenjaminCox I spend my programming life mainly doing back end and/or internal stuff, so yes I suppose the latter. I have just been playing around benchmarking a few different scenarios with this - size of content, number of files, bandwidth, latency (albeit artificial), varying caching headers - and it is making for an interesting Monday evening. Unsurprisingly there is a considerable performance drop of with a *very* large number of files but on "fast" connections (200K/s+) there is a definite gain from two files transferred concurrently, and no noticeable drop off as bandwidth decreases.

Comment: @DaveRandom that's not a bad way to spend a Monday evening...  hope it's both illuminating and fun!  Don't know what you're using for latency and whatnot, but I've been a huge fan of Charles proxy on Mac for some of that sort of informal testing.

Comment: @BenjaminCox I work for a telecoms company and have about £2K worth of Cisco switch in my cellar for my geeking pleasure :-D I also have a decidedly lower tech but very effective trick to "simulate" noisy networks, and that is to plug a switch into itself and send a few broadcast packets out to the network, and watch it all fall apart. Unfortunately I have to bypass my expensive switch for that as it's too darn clever and shuts the ports off in about 2 seconds. It's a good trick though if you want to test the resiliency of (or maliciously break) a network.

Answer (score 3):

"I've been looking at some other high traffic sites and no one else seems to be doing this"

Really?  That surprises me quite a bit...  it's kind of considered step one for decreasing page load times.  See here: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html.  If you want to test adherence to load time best practices, you may also want to try their performance testing tool YSlow:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/.

Here's why this is considered a best practice:  browsers have a limit of around 8 simultaneous connections, and a limit of 2 (more for non-conforming browsers) per specific server.  So if you're producing multiple files for a given page then they will load somewhat serially, since your browser will make fifteen round-trips to your server, two at a time.

So let's see how this plays out.  Suppose you've got fifteen files at 10k each, or you could munge them together into a 150k file.  Say the latency to the server is 65ms, and the download rate is a measly 25k/sec.  Let's do the math... here's the equation:

```
$page_load_time = ( ($simultaneous_connections * $load_time_per_file) 
                       + $latency_per_request ) 
                  * ($number_of_files/$request_cycles)
```

Where:

```
$request_cycles = max(1, ($number_of_files/$simultaneous_connections))
```

So, with 15 files at 10k each:

```
((2 * .4 seconds) + .065 seconds) * 7.5 =  6.4875 seconds
```

or with a single 150k file:

```
((1 * 6 seconds) + 0.065 seconds) * 1 = 6.065 seconds
```

Not a dramatic difference, but still almost half a second of user waiting time!

Now - what happens when they're on a 3g connection?  Or having a little wi-fi trouble?  Let's try more bandwidth (100k/sec) and more latency (250ms):

```
((2 * .1 seconds) + 0.250 seconds) * 7.5 = 3.375 seconds
```

or

```
((1 * 1.5 seconds) + 0.250 seconds) * 1 = 1.750 seconds
```

Woah!  Now all those separate little files has almost doubled the page load time!

Add in a whole bunch of other files, your fancy TypeKit load, ad server load, Facebook plugins, etc. etc. etc. and this stuff starts to matter even more.

Comment: You do make a good case here so I shall tentatively award you a +1, although I do still disagree at least in part, I think that a good client caching header setup is more important in the long run. But I have to say you make your case well.

Comment: @DaveRandom - thanks, Dave!  You'll get no objection from me on the importance of good caching headers...  but there's another mole to whack once that's taken care of.